# Frequency response of amplifier intuition understanding

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, cmos, frequency-response

I am facing problem in basic understanding of frequency response of amplifier.
According to this here(my textbook):

"Each capacitor has a region of activity in the frequency domain, which starts from “where it comes out of the open circuit state” to “where it enters the short circuit state.” It is obvious that the open circuit and short circuit concepts discussed here are relative and are determined in a compar- ison with the adjacent impedances."

and it also says:

"Each capacitor, including both the internal and the external ones, contrib- utes to the amplifier’s transfer function by introducing a zero and a pole. At low frequencies, each capacitor’s region of activity starts with a zero and ends with a pole."

and for high frequency:

"The frequency at which an internal capacitor comes out of the open-circuit state is indeed its pole, and its zero is where it enters the short circuit state."

**What I dont understand is how does the author says that say for high frequency the open circuit state is a pole and not a zero??
How does he intuitively says that??**

If I try to think I see the A(s) function and see that at poles A(s) becomes infinite and at at zeros A(s) becomes zero, How do you associate the open circuit and short circuit thing with either a pole and zero??
Also he defines the transfer function as(please see image below) [image]

I dont get it, Isn't pole and zero -p<sub>i</sub> and -z<sub>i</sub> and not +p<sub>i</sub> and +z<sub>i</sub>. It's the same case for most of the books(they also define it that way)?? Am i missing something here??

I am posting image of my textbook page here:
[image]

Comment: I won't be buying that book.

Comment: why?? Isn't it trying to explain what's actually happening in the circuit. The book is Analysis of Bipolar and CMOS Amplifiers
By Amir M. Sodagar. Please tell me whats wrong in that book.You can download it here http://tinyurl.com/gw8c9gu   use mirror libgen to download it

Comment: I just don't like the use of the term "where it comes out of the open circuit state" - that put me off right away and NO I'm not downloading it.

Comment: I also dont like the book. But now since I have heard its argument, I can't find a fallacy and I'm stuck.:P

Comment: Is your problem not understanding how a capacitor can produce a pole at low frequencies in one situation and a pole at high frequencies in another situation? Ditto the production of zeros.

Comment: i dont get why a zero??

Comment: If the capacitor is used as a parallel impedance then it forms a zero at high frequencies. If it is used as a series impedance then it forms a zero at low frequencies.

Comment: how do you go about proving it?? Can you refer me a book.

Comment: what about sign of pole and zero....i dont get it...shouldnt pole and zero frequencies be negetive(if we see the transfer function)??? what does it mean??

Answer (score 1):

Shubham Cgawla, do you know where the terms "zero" and "pole" come from? Both terms are related to the complex frequency variable s (which is a theoretical one only).

For example, the first-order lowpass transfer is H(s)=1/(1+s/wo). This function has a pole (zero denominator) for s=-wo. But note, this is a pure theoretical (artificial) consideration only, because we never can produce a frequency "-wo" (there are no negative frequencies).

Instead, for frequency analyses, we simply set s=jw and find the magnitude of the complex expression [1/(1+jw/wo)]. And - as a result - we get the result that for w=wo the magnitude is 3dB below its maximum (in this case: maximum is "1"). And this statement (cut-off frequency at w=wo) is equivalent to saying "pole at w=wo".

For a simple RC highpass we can apply similar considerations which lead to a system "zero".

Summary: The terms "pole" and "zero" are defined for the complex variable s only. But that does not mean that at w=wo the magnitude of such functions becomes zero or infinite in reality. The concept of poles and zeros is only a nice tool to describe the properties of frequency-dependent networks in the complex frequency domain.

**EDIT** (Answer to the question in bold):
Quote: *The frequency at which an internal capacitor comes out of the open-circuit state is indeed its pole, and its zero is where it enters the short circuit state."*

I think, this is a rather "problematic" and unprofessional description. Let´s take - as an example - again the first-order RC lowpass. For very low frequencies the impedance of the capacitor is very large (theoreticcaly infinite for DC). Hence, for some rough calculations it could be approximated as an open circuit. Writing "...comes out of the open-circuit state..." means that the capacitive impedance is in the transition region between "infinite" and finite values which must be taken into account. It can be assumed that the author means the 3dB-corner frequency (which in the complex frequency domain is equivalent to the pole frequency).

Comment: Thanks I got one concept clear(sorry for the dumbness). But can you please explain the thing written in bold in question.

Comment: Yes - I have tried it. See EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a low pass RC filter and a high pass RC filter: -

[image]

Their respective frequency responses are: -

[image]

At high frequencies a capacitor begins to act like a short-circuit. This is because Q = C.V and therefore I = C.dv/dt. This means that when dv/dt is high, you get more current i.e. at higher frequencies dv/dt is greater hence the impedance of the capacitor falls.

Answer (score 0):

Shubham, since your last comment ended in a question, I think you are still looking for more explanation.  Here is my attempt.  I'm going to reference Andy's diagrams because they are good for understanding what is going on.  I think you know, because you wouldn't be reading this text if you didn't, that a capacitor is an open circuit at 0 Hz and a short at infinity.  In Andy's low pass example you can probably come up with the transfer function Vo=Vi * 1/(RCS+1).  Similarly the high pass is Vi * RCS/(RCS+1).  Both of these functions have a pole that can be found by solving (RCS+1)=0.  The result is S=-1/RC.  In addition the The low pass has a zero at infinity.  You see this by taking the limit as S goes to infinity.  It is the interaction of the pole at -1/RC and the zero at infinity that give the low pass shape.  The high pass has a zero at 0, because of RCS in the numerator.  The interaction of this zero with the pole gives the high pass shape.

It might help you to look at the graphic solution.  I'll try to describe how to do this for the high pass case.  In the complex plane you draw vectors from the poles and zeros to the frequency on the positive jw axis.  Then divide the length from the pole into the length from the zero.  At 0 this is easy because the the length from the zero is zero and the result is 0.  Now if we pick 1/RC on the jw axis, the length from the zero is 1/RC and the length of the vector from the pole is root 2 times 1/RC.  The division gives 0.707 which is why the function is at -3db.  If you draw the vectors to very high frequencies their lengths start to look equal.  So at high frequencies the gain approaches one.

So I think the answer is that the poles are negative.  The poles are not where the capacitor is open or short.  The poles are where S=-1/RC and this occurs somewhere between where the capacitor looks like an open or short.